# query on the time taken for rest api in kubernetes environment

Tags: spring-boot, performance, rest, kubernetes

I have a REST API running in a Kubernetes namespace. This REST API will in turn call another REST API on the same Kubernetes namespace. Sometimes the calls take within 10 milliseconds. Someother times it takes more than a second to respond. How can I check why its taking more than 500 milliseconds in some instances?

The REST API is developed using SpringBoot. I have also done good amount of performance testing and monitored the same using JCMD tool, Visual VM tools. I did not find significant issue with the REST API.

Comment: How are accessing the internal API? Are you using an internal kubernetes service DNS? Which base image did you use for your container?

Comment: I am using alpine linux with openjdk11. the app in the Kubernetes namespace is using "inter pod communication" to talk to other pods.

Comment: We've ran into similar issues when invoking rapid requests that require DNS resolving. Since Alpine doesn't cache what it resolves that can create serious performance issues. Read this for more info and ways to mitigate - https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/master/docs/caveats.md#dns